# Print function on jQuery SimpleModal

Tags: jquery, printing, popup, simplemodal

I'm using the Basic Modal Dialog from here http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/ and inside of this dialog, I have an image which I would like to add a Print button below it.

I've tried using jqPrint but it doesn't work. Is there something that I've missed?

My popup dialog

```
<div id="popup_name" class="popup_block">
<div class="map"><img src="images/map.png"></div>
<br><a href="#" id="print"><img src="images/print.png"></a>
</div>
```

jqPrint

```
$("#print").click( function() { 
$('.map').jqprint(); 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: code looks fine..which browser are u using.....and make sure u close <img> tag properly and open <script> tag properly...jqprint() is a plug-in make sure u add proper reference...

Comment: Using Firefox. Also tried on Chrome but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Is it giving any error..or simply no response....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMP: `jqprint()` is a plug-in, add proper reference to your file.
Try putting your click function in document.ready, it should work fine then.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#print").click( function() { 
$('.map').jqprint(); 
});
});
```

I have tested this, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think the click event is not getting triggered try using live.

```
 $("#print").live('click', function(event){
    $('.map').jqprint();
  });
```

Comment: Tried but still no prompt to print :(

Comment: @doodoodukes try adding alert inside this function and make sure that the click event is getting triggered.